# cleaner way to parse data

Tags: php, parsing

I have 9 checkboxes on a form and I'm doing the following:

```
//names of $_POST checkboxes

$interests = array("energy","recycling","composting","electric","climate","gas",
"pesticides","water","other");
$ival=[];

if($_POST["energy"] === "on")$ival[0]=true;
else $ival[0]=false;

if($_POST["recycling"] === "on")$ival[1]=true;
else $ival[1]=false;

if($_POST["composting"] === "on")$ival[2]=true;
else $ival[2]=false;

if($_POST["electric"] === "on")$ival[3]=true;
else $ival[3]=false;

if($_POST["climate"] === "on")$ival[4]=true;
else $ival[4]=false;

if($_POST["gas"] === "on")$ival[5]=true;
else $ival[5]=false;

if($_POST["pesticides"] === "on")$ival[6]=true;
else $ival[6]=false;

if($_POST["water"] === "on")$ival[7]=true;
else $ival[7]=false;

if($_POST["other"] === "on")$ival[8]=true;
else $ival[8]=false;

for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
    query ("insert into interest (usr,
                                  subject,
                                  value)
                                  values(?,?,?)",
                                  $usr,$interests[$i],$ival[$i]);

 }
```

Is there a way to avoid all these if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `if` statements. The result of a comparison is `true` or `false`, so you can use it directly.

You can use `array_map()` to create the array instead of lots of separate assignments.

```
$ival = array_map(function($interest) { return $_POST[$interest] === "on"; }, $interests);
```

But you don't really need the `$ival` array, you can loop over `$interests` and perform the queries there.

```
foreach ($interests as $interest) {
    query("insert into interest (usr, subject, value) values (?, ?, ?)",
          $usr, $interest, $_POST[$interest] === "on");
}
```